# Fullpage.js by Scrolling down scroll horizontally and on one Section go down after finishing scrol horizontal again?

Tags: javascript, css, fullpage.js

With Fullpage.js i would like to only use Scrolling down to navigate to next page which is horizontally. On one Page I would like to go down a few slides, navigate vertically. After these are finished I would like to go to next slide which is horizontally again.

I got it working when my Slide which is going to scroll vertically is the last slide. But cannot get it to work when it's in the middle of the slides.

I made a picture to show what i mean:

[image]

Comment: I think your question is missing the code html and Javascript you used with fullpage.js, for someone that knows this library to help you find what is wrong.

Comment: I second @el-teedee. By adding code into your question you increase the chances of receiving help and reduce the chances to have your question flagged and removed.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is not the right one.
The image should look like this instead:

[image]

That is, 3 vertical sections.
The fist and last sections with with 2 horizontal slides each.

This way you will only need to make use of the fullPage.js extension called [Scroll Horizontally](https://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/extensions/scroll-horizontally.html) and you'll have exactly what you want.

1. Scroll down from 1 will lead to 2.
2. Scroll down from 2 will lead to 3.
3. Scroll down from 3 will lead to 4.
4. Scroll down from 4 will lead to 5.